# "Warmed" vs "warmed up."

Tags: word-choice

When to use the former and when to use the later?

Example sentence:

> Seeing how devoted she was to me, my heart warmed (up).

Should there be an *up*? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reserve the idiomatic "warmed up" for things like coffee, yesterday's meatloaf, etc.  Mainly things relating to temperature.

*"I warmed up my tea that got cold."*
*"I went inside to warm up."*

I wouldn't recommend using it for more abstract ideas.
*"The card from my grandson warmed my heart."*

These are not definitive rules, just suggestions.  Your sentence with the "warmed up" would be fine in most contexts.

Comment: I think you're correct. Warmed up is for exercise and liquids.

Comment: That said, there are plenty of uses of "warm up" for non-literal contexts, like [this 1986 article "Warming Up Soviet-Japanese Relations"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01636608609477355?journalCode=rwaq20).  I think a big hint is in your example "the card *warmed my heart*" rather than "my heart warmed" - *warmed* is often transitive, meaning "to heat something else".

Comment: Not just exercise, but also musical performance: singers "warm up" before a concert, for example.